# Change current page to account of it's own

Tags: facebook-pages

I currently have a business Facebook page connected to my personal Facebook . How do I make that page an account of it's own and keep all the likes and history?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, create a new profile or account for your business, then using the current profile make the newly created account admin of the page and then remove yourself as admin.